# Get current InstanceId in AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am using the AWS CloudWatch SDK to record metrics from a program running inside EC2 instance. I would like to report back the InstanceId as a dimension for these metrics. How do I find out the EC2 InstanceId from a Java program running inside the instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [EC2MetadataUtils](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/EC2MetadataUtils.html).

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.internal.util.EC2MetadataUtils;

String instanceId = EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId();
```